# Qt 5.2.1 with MinGW 4.8 32bit wont run applications on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, qt

Using Qt Creator 3.0.1, Qt 5.2.1, MinGW 4.8 32bit on Windows 8.1 64bit, I am able to build an application but not run it.

When trying to debug the application (new clean project), the output tells me

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platfor plugin "windows".  Available platform plugins are: minimal,
>   offscreen. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

follow by a

> Runtime Error!
>
> Program C:\Qt\Qt5.2.1\test\debug\test.exe
>
> This application requested the runtime to terminate in an unusual way
>   etc...

I tried adding the qwindows.dll's under my /debug/platforms/*.dll but no difference there. 
Is my problem due to my Windows installation?

*EDIT*: After trying out @paulm's solution, putting the windows dll's inside `plugins` instead, nothing changes. 
Dependancy Walker tells me that I miss

> ```
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
> API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL 
> API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
> ```

**EDIT2**

After adding these DLL's (had to download them [from here](http://www.dllme.com/dll/files/api_ms_win_core_kernel32_private_l1.html)) and seing I had to change the name of one of the DLL's I downloaded from this site, I now get the new error

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the
>   Qt platform plugin "windows".
>
> Available platform plugins are: minimal, offscreen

And not the following runtime error. 
Since I had to go to external sources to get the Microsoft DLL's, doesn't this really points to something faulty with the Windows 8.1 DLL's?

**EDIT3:**

To clarify, in my \platforms I have

> qminimal.dll
>  
>   qmoffscreen.dll 
>   qwindows.dll

whilst in my \plugins I copied the same DLL's.

Comment: create a directory called plugins and put the windows.dll in there, then use depends.exe to grab any other missing dlls

Comment: @paulm You mean qwindows.dll? I did so, but nothing changes. Still, not being able to run from Creator should not be solved by this, would it?

Answer (score 0):

All required steps are described on [this page of the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#application-dependencies). Check especially the "plugandpaint" example under ["Creating the application package"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment-windows.html#creating-the-application-package).

My guess is that you are missing the second one:

```
myapp.exe
platform/qwindows.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
```

And yes, dependency management on Windows is a pain. It should be part of the OS, instead, it's not, and you have to take care of everything yourself.

Comment: I got'em all :\ EDIT: Please check my edited question

Comment: @Wilhelmsen the *core* DLLs are somewhere deep inside the Windows directory, and shouldn't be a problem. These are found by black voodoo magic by the Windows executable loader. The error output does show you're missing `platform/qwindows.dll`. Or are you trying to get a debug version to run? In that case you'd need `platform/qwindowsd.dll` and all `Qt5*d.dll` versions.

Comment: That is what I thought as well, but I have always had those dll's there. I am trying to run the release candidate, so I have none of the *d.dll. I added those for good measure but no difference.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Then something must be wrong with your setup. I doubt running a debugger will help pin down the issue. The only thing I can tell you is to remove *all* Qt things from your PC, and reinstall/rebuild everything. Are you 100% sure there are no other qwindows.dll files interfering?

Comment: How could other dll's be interfering? I have absolutely no other Qt installations than the one mentioned. I first tried the application stand alone with no Qt installation. Then I tried installing Creator and SDK, but I then discovered that even that doesn't work.

Comment: Just installing the Qt SDK won't make your application find the Qt DLLs. You have to copy them yourself alongside your application. If that doesn't work, I don't know what to tell you. It should, and it does for many people. Did you follow the steps in the link exactly? Did you try copying the other (ANGLE, ICU, d3d, EGL) DLLs as described? Did you also copy the GCC runtime library (libgcc/libstdc++) DLLs? These last ones are always necessary for any GCC-compiled C++ program that was dynamically linked.

Comment: I installed the SDK just to test if it worked from the Qt IDE. My application runs just fine on Windows 7 (standalone with all necessary DLLs copied with it), but I haven't tried copying in the GCC runtime libraries DLLs. Thank you for all your help, but since it works on w7, I did everything everyone is saying to make it work with w8.1 I guess I am lost. Seriously, a blank Qt Creator project won't even run!